# Copying a model to another database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, model, eloquent

I have a ticket model related to other models. When the ticket is cancelled, I need to copy the ticket with its relationships into another database (called closed_tickets). I have set up the closed_tickets database to be exactly the same as the original one, with the same relations (I used php artisan migrate --database="closed_tickets").

How should I go about this?

Comment: Do you mean a separate database? As in a separate database connection with separate tables? Or do you mean just another table within the same database?

Comment: May I ask why you are using 2 identical tables? Instead of adding a field status with an enum saying it is closed or open (if not a tinyint saying closed/open)

Comment: @Samsquanch Yes a seperate database.

Comment: @AneesSaban Because I have foreign key relations set up. I want the info in the closed_tickets database to unchange if I were to change any info another table in the original DB table such as users.

Comment: I would think it would be simpler to create a new `Status` model that belongs to a ticket. Then you just query all the tickets that have a closed status.